# My program that should display a N even digit number shows mess

Tags: c++

So recently i got a programing task from a contest and my code should display the N 
even digit number from 0. In even digit numbers all numbers must be dividable by 2. When i input the number 12 it should show the number 44 on the output but it shous some kind of a mess. here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
   int kturaParzysta = 1;
   int N;
   cin >> N;
   int tab[N];
   for(int i = 0; i < N;i++){
       string cyfraStr = to_string(N);
       bool parzystocyfrowa = true;
       for(int j = 0;j <= cyfraStr.length();j++){
           if(int(cyfraStr[j]) % 2 != 0){
               parzystocyfrowa = false;
           }
       }

       if(parzystocyfrowa){
           tab[kturaParzysta] = i; 
           kturaParzysta++;
       }
   }
   cout << tab[N - 1];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Idk why it even compiled

Comment: You're exceeding the boundaries of `tab`, which you shouldn't be using anyway, as VLAs aren't standard in C++. Why do you think you need an array for this anyway?

Comment: *it shous some kind of mess* is not a useful problem description. What kind of *mess* does it show? We can't see your screen from where we are, so you need to provide the information in your post. What does using the debugger to step through the code tell you about what it's doing?

Comment: @KenWhite This is clearly a task for beginners in programming, regardless the language. Beginners usually don't know how to use a debugger.

Comment: @ProXicT: There's no better time to learn to use one than at the beginning. It helps you to better understand what's happening in the code and teaches problem solving skills that will be needed later. It's never too early to start learning how to use the best tool a programmer can have in their toolbox.

Comment: I agree with @KenWhite. The sooner one learns how to use a debugger, the better.

Comment: @KenWhite I agree that debugger is very useful, however, it's quite hard to grasp it when learning your first programming language. Imagine you don't know anything about programming and suddenly you have to know what stack is, what backtrace is, memory layout, etc. It's just too much for beginners.

Comment: @ProXicT: No one said anything about looking at stack traces or memory layout. Simply stepping through the code line by line as it executes to you can see exactly what it's doing is enough to start, which is precisely what I suggested. It's never too early to learn how to trace through your code logic, and it will solve the vast majority of problems that new coders experience.

Comment: @boyanhristov96 I agree, but at the very beginning of learning programming, which is the stage the OP is at right now, at least according to the question, it is way too soon, I think.

Comment: @KenWhite You're right, but it depends on what platform you're on. I can imagine that getting the debugger to work is easier in Visual Studio, for example, than in Linux with GDB. By that I'm not implying that the debugger in Visual Studio is any better than GDB, just that the integration in the IDE, which not everyone can afford, can be helpful.

Comment: Yes, that is also true. In the very very early stage it will be too much to use a debugger.

Comment: I removed the array and it works